# Como leer un arreglo de archivo txt en c# y colocar los diferentes datos en Textbox

Tags: mysql, c#, txt

Hola soy principiante en el tema de la programación y estoy desarrollando una app ,desconozco si esta pregunta se ha realizado con anterioridad, pero deseo saber como crear un arreglo en archivo de texto que me guarde la cadena de conexión de mi Base de Datos con títulos, y que a la vez también lea el arreglo y e inserte partes especificas de texto en los Textbox

Por el momento tengo lo siguiente que se encarga de escribir y guardar el txt con los datos.

```
        string[] texto = { "Server",servidor.Text, "User", usuario.Text, "Pass", contraseña.Text, "DB", base_dato.Text };
        using (StreamWriter arreglo = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Jesus\\Documents\\arreglo.txt"))

       
        foreach (string linea in texto)
        {
                arreglo.WriteLine(linea);     
            
        }
```

Pero tambien necesito uno que me lea todo los datos en el txt y lo inserte en el textbox o lo guarde en variables

Gracias Anticipadas

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si tenes el writeline.. tambien tenes un readline, no??? ;)

Comment: Hola , ok, Gracias . 

no lo único que realice intentando leer los datos del arreglo fue esto 


          
           string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Jesus\\Documents\\arreglo.txt");
       Console.WriteLine( contraseña.Text, "Pass");

pero no me resulta

Comment: que quiere decir no me resulta? eso resulta a la perfeccion, deja una linea del archivo en cada fila del array lineas...

Comment: arregla tu pregunta... ordena tus problemas... o sea, ni siquiera te fijaste que te habia quedado en la variable al hacer el readall??? lo que queres se hace con un substring...

Comment: Lo siento, es que aun soy nuevo en el tema y despacio voy aprendiendo cada cosa , ¿A que te refieres con que se me quedo una variable?

¿Como se haria con un SubString?

Comment: no hay problema con que vayas todo lo despacio que necesites... Pero en lugar de analizar tu problema, estas buscando que te lo resolvamos a cuenta gotas... Si lograste guardar las cosas en el archivo, y luego lograste leerlas, quiere decir que en esa variable donde leiste todo el archivo, estan todos tus datos... ahora que tenes todos los datos, podes ver el contenido, y de ahi avanzar, no?

Comment: Intente hacer lo que me dijiste de buscar un SubString , pero no lo entendi. 


lo que me resulta es lo siguiente, pero no es tal como desearia 

`string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Jesus\\Documents\\arreglo.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(contraseña.Text = lineas[5].ToString(), usuario.Text = lineas[3].ToString(), servidor.Text = lineas[1].ToString(), contraseña.Text = lineas[7].ToString(), base_dato.Text = lineas[5].ToString());`


Agradezco tu tiempo y me disculpo por las molestias.

Comment: lo que estas haciendo, esta perfecto.. cual seria el problema con eso?